# Php script stuck at "new Mongo()" while using Apache

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I wrote a little php login script. It searches in a mongoDb-collection for the provided credentials. If i run it from console with

```
php login.php
```

it runs flawless. However, if i try to log in from the html-interface it seems to be stuck at

```
$m = new Mongo(...);
```

directive, and doesn't continue with the other lines of code.
I'm running over an apache server on my laptop, just to try what i'm doing.

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things you will need to check are:

1: Is mongo enabled in your php.ini?
2: If you using a recent version of php then try changing it from

```
$m = new Mongo();
```

to

```
$m = new MongoClient();
```

Comment: 1) Yes, in my php.ini file i have:

    extension = mongo.so

2) I've already tried with:

    new MongoClient() 

    new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

but it continues to stuck. Thanks anyway

Comment: is it possible that your cli version of php differs from the one that serves your sites?

Comment: That's the same version i suppose, because apache use the same version of PHP that i use for the command line

Comment: [EDIT] I resolved including mongo.so in apache2/php.ini. Sorry, my fault.